# opening same file on dropbox of two different computers(usernames)

Tags: python

i work on python.  I have written some codes that i could run via dropbox on different computers( having their various usernames). like this

computer 1:

```
file=open("/User/james/Dropbox/programming/MATLAB/ViralGOgeneclustering/600_Clusters/complete.csv")
```

computer 2:

```
file = open("/User/oyebodmas/Dropbox/programming/MATLAB/ViralGOgeneclustering/600_Clusters/complete.csv")
```

each time i have to switch between computers. i always have to change the usename from james to oyebodmas and vice versa. how could i program the computer to ignore the username and read the file. i have tried

```
file = open("~/Dropbox/programming/MATLAB/ViralGOgeneclustering/600_Clusters/complete.csv")
```

but it does not work. thank you.

Comment: Can you download it to one place? You can add in your computer a new Driver that will be the same

Answer (score 2):

For a multiplatform solution, you can do this, assuming the folders you want to access are user's home folders:

```
import os

home = os.path.expanduser("~")

file_location = os.path.join(home, "Dropbox/programming/MATLAB/ViralGOgeneclustering/600_Clusters/complete.csv")

myfile = open(file_location)
```

In the case they are not, and the path is always the same and differs only in the username, you can build the path as shown in [TimPietzcker's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22961283/2842884) answer.

Comment: This looks much nicer than my solution.

Comment: Niceness is an arbitrary category. I would say it is more robust.

Comment: Yes. Robustness is nice :)

Comment: Don't use `file` as a variable name.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: undelete your question, I am referencing to it, it can be correct in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on a *NIX system, so I can't test this, but could you try

```
import os
currentuser = os.getusername()
file_location = os.path.join("/User", currentuser)
file_location = os.path.join(file_location, "Dropbox/programming/MATLAB/ViralGOgeneclustering/600_Clusters/complete.csv")
myfile = open(file_location)
```